# Fatal error when adapting my extension for Joomla 3

Tags: joomla3.0

I am trying to adapt my extension for Joomla 3 and I am getting the following error 
[image]

As you can see the Call Stack does not help a lot..

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can post some code from your app...

Comment: Is the isis-Template the extension you are working on, or is there a chance to use another template?